# decorators execution of python

Tags: python, python-decorators

```
registry = []
def register(func):
 print('running register(%s)' % func)
 registry.append(func)
 return func

@register
def f1():
 print('running f1()')
@register
def f2():
 print('running f2()')
def f3():
 print('running f3()')
def main():
  print('running main()')
  print('registry ->', registry)
  f1()
  f2()
  f3()
if __name__=='__main__':
  main()
```

in the above program why doesnt the f1() f2() and f3() in main work if return func is not used in the register function

Comment: I don't understand your question. What does it mean to say that the functions "doesn't  ... work"? I ran your code and it runs exactly how I would expect it to run. Apparently you expect something else -- but what? Please explain.

Comment: what i mean is if the return func statement in line 5 is omitted from the code why doesnt the program work..what is the significance of return func in line 5

Comment: I missed the significance of the stipulation that it doesn't work *if* the line `return func` is deleted from the definition of the decorator.

Answer (score 1):

A decorator is a higher-order function which takes a function as input and returns a function as output. Decorator syntax is a way of calling this higher order function.

The lines

```
@register
def f1():
 print('running f1()')
```

are *equivalent* to the lines

```
def f1():
 print('running f1()')

f1 = register(f1)
```

Usually, the decorator modifies the decorated function. In this case it is returned unmodified. But -- it is still returned. If the decorator returned nothing then the decorator would replace `f1` by `None` (which wouldn't be very useful). This particular decorator is called for its side effects (registering a function). The fact that it returns an unmodified function doesn't mean that it isn't called.

The output that you see should make sense now:

```
running register(<function f1 at 0x0000000001DCCBF8>)
running register(<function f2 at 0x0000000003566D90>)
running main()
registry -> [<function f1 at 0x0000000001DCCBF8>, <function f2 at 0x0000000003566D90>]
running f1()
running f2()
running f3()
```

You used `@register` twice, which calls `register()` twice, *before* main is run. Neither `f1` nor `f2` were actually changed by the decorator, hence they work as expected when called in `main()`. The printed value of `registry` shows that the decorator worked as intended: it registered the decorated `f1, f2` but didn't register the undecorated `f3`.

On the other hand, if you remove the line `return func` from the decorator, you see (something like):

```
running register(<function f1 at 0x00000000004DCBF8>)
running register(<function f2 at 0x0000000003586D90>)
running main()
registry -> [<function f1 at 0x00000000004DCBF8>, <function f2 at 0x0000000003586D90>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jcoleman\Documents\Programs\PythonScripts\socode.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\jcoleman\Documents\Programs\PythonScripts\socode.py", line 64, in main
    f1()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

The decorator is still called twice -- but they are now (implicitly) returning `None`. As soon as `f1()` is hit in `main` you get a run-time error since at that stage `f1` is `None`, which isn't callable.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/739654/4996248) question for more on decorators.